# Typescript unknown type can't be used with ?. operator

Tags: typescript

In my application I save settings to a json file.  As new versions of the application gets released, more things get added to the json file.  That means the application might load a json settings file from an older version which is missing some settings.

After loading the Json file I store its contents in a variable (loadedUserPreferenceData) that is declared to be of type unknown.

I'd like to do things like this:

```
const width  = loadedUserPreferenceData?.ui?.windowSize?.x ?? CONSTANTS.sizes.rendererWindow.defaultSize.x;
```

but I get an error because loadedUserPreferenceData of type unknown.  I can get around this by casting the variable to any like this:

```
const width  = ( loadedUserPreferenceData as any )?.ui?.windowSize?.x ?? CONSTANTS.sizes.rendererWindow.defaultSize.x;
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to handle this?  I'm surprised the ?. operator can not be used with unknown types.

Comment: maybe create an interface that matches your json config

Comment: I have an interface that defines what the "current" version of the json file should contain, but I don't have an interface that defines all the previous "possible" old versions that the json file might contain.  Not sure what is a good way to support older versions of the json file that still needs to be loaded.